# String Split PHP PREG_MATCH

Tags: php, arrays, split, preg-match

I have a string :

```
$productList="
Saluran Dua(Bothway)-(TAN007);
Memo-(T-Memo);
7-Pak FBIP  R-100.000-(F1R100);
FBIP LOKAL 350 Mnt  (R/N/M)-(FL350);
FBIP SLJJ 30+300 Mnt (R)-(FJ30R)
";
```

i want the result like this:

```
Array(
[0]=>Saluran Dua(Bothway)
[1]=>Memo
[2]=>7-Pak FBIP  R-100.000
[3]=>FBIP LOKAL 350 Mnt  (R/N/M)
[4]=>FBIP SLJJ 30+300 Mnt (R)
);
```

I used :

```
$separator = '#\;([a-zA-Z/0-9()\- ]*)\-#';
preg_match_all($separator, $productList, $match);
$value=$match[1];
```

but the result:

```
Array(
[0] => Saluran Dua Arah(BothWay)
[1] => Memo-(T
[2] => 7-Pak FBIP  R
[3] => FBIP LOKAL 350 Mnt  (R/N/M)
);
```

i hope someone can help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape your parenthesis

```
$separator = '#([a-zA-Z0-9. \-\(\)/+]+)-\([a-zA-Z0-9. \-/]+\);{0,1}#';
```

Comment: sorry,but it changes nothing @HalayemAnis

Comment: @DimasW i have corrected my mistake... hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match_all` function.

```
$productList= <<< EOT
Saluran Dua(Bothway)-(TAN007);
Memo-(T-Memo);
7-Pak FBIP  R-100.000-(F1R100);
FBIP LOKAL 350 Mnt  (R/N/M)-(FL350);
FBIP SLJJ 30+300 Mnt (R)-(FJ30R)
EOT;
preg_match_all('~(?m)^.*?(?=-\()~', $productList, $match);
print_r($match[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Saluran Dua(Bothway)
    [1] => Memo
    [2] => 7-Pak FBIP  R-100.000
    [3] => FBIP LOKAL 350 Mnt  (R/N/M)
    [4] => FBIP SLJJ 30+300 Mnt (R)
)
```

`(?=-\()` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by a dash and an opening parenthesis.